# ASP.NET-5 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-core

Can I create ASP.NET-5 projects in Visual Studio 2013 somehow?
Also share please links with documentation, examples or anything that could help to create project using mvc6 that used to be on web api.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer is not. I'm pretty sure, vNext is such big change in Microsoft technologies that they will not put any effort in adding that vs2013, you can get vs2015 community edition is very complete free version of visual studio.

this [link](http://www.asp.net/vnext) is very good starting point.